# Appengine modules dispatch.xml routing with custom domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-module, app-engine-modules

I have someone got appengine modules working. i have two modules, **app** and **auth**. i have a custom domain say **domain.com**, i want to route **app.domain.com** to app module, and **auth.domain.com** to auth modules, following is my dispatch.xml file,

```
<dispatch>
    <!-- Default module serves simple hostname request. -->
    <url>*/favicon.ico</url>
    <module>default</module>
</dispatch>

<dispatch>
    <!-- Auth Service to auth module -->
    <url>auth./*</url>
    <module>auth</module>
</dispatch>

<dispatch>
    <!-- Default module serves simple hostname request. -->
    <url>*/favicon.ico</url>
    <module>default</module>
</dispatch>
```

since app module is default app.domain.com is successfully routed, but i couldn't able to route auth.domain.com to auth module, its always pointing to default module,

how can i route custom domain to server specific module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full hostname:

```
<dispatch>
  <-- * in front of hostname (*auth) is optional -->
  <-- it allows for subdomain (version) mapping  -->
  <url>*auth.hostname.com/*</url>  
  <module>auth</module>
</dispatch>
```

You should also consider configuring the [subdomain wildcard mapping](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more%5fabout%5fwildcard%5fsubdomain%5fmapping): then GAE will allow you to map to particular module versions, e.g.

```
auth.hostname.com -> auth module, default version
v1.auth.hostname.com -> auth module, version v1
```

This is useful for using SSL during development, when you want to directly address particular version of a module.

Comment: i tried this but no luck , auth.domain.com still pointing to default version

Comment: We are using this setup in our app and it works. Make sure there is not something else wrong.

Comment: Its working now with this routing, the problem was with domain cname mapping, its fixed now thanks!